# java byte[] type property not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, byte, getter

I have a class which has this property:

```
byte[] image;
```

It also has a getter and setter which I believe are properly implemented:

```
public byte[] getImage(){
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image){
    this.image = image;
}
```

However I still get the following error message after building and deploying:
    Invalid property 'image' of bean class [com.winstant.boma2.formdata.content.CarouselFormData]: Bean property 'image' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

STACK TRACE:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'image' of bean class [com.winstant.boma2.formdata.content.CarouselFormData]: Bean property 'image' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:858)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.content.add_002dcarousel_jsp._jspService(add_002dcarousel_jsp.java:221)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'image' of bean class [com.winstant.boma2.formdata.content.CarouselFormData]: Bean property 'image' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:709)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:701)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:218)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag.doStartTagInternal(BindTag.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.bootstrap.input_tag.doTag(input_tag.java:159)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.content.add_002dcarousel_jsp._jspx_meth_bootstrap_005finput_005f0(add_002dcarousel_jsp.java:241)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.content.add_002dcarousel_jsp._jspService(add_002dcarousel_jsp.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

JSP VIEW:

```
    <%@ taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="bootstrap" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/bootstrap" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="winstant" uri="http://tags.winstant.com/jsp/winstant"%>
    <%@ page session="false" %>
    <c:set var="mainBody">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" id="list-form-container">
    <form:form method="post" class="form-horizontal well" modelAttribute="carouselFormData"  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/content/carousel/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Add Carousel</legend>
    <bootstrap:input path="image" label="Image">
    <form:input path="image" type="file" cssClass="input-xlarge"/>
    </bootstrap:input>
    <bootstrap:input path="imgSrc" label="Filename">
    <form:input path="imgSrc" cssClass="input-xlarge"/>
    </bootstrap:input>
    <bootstrap:input path="imgAlt" label="Image Alt">
    <form:textarea path="imgAlt" cols="5" rows="10" cssClass="span4" />
    </bootstrap:input>
    <bootstrap:input path="caption" label="Caption">
    <form:textarea path="caption" cols="5" rows="10" cssClass="span4"/>
    </bootstrap:input>
    <bootstrap:input path="active" label="Active?">
    <bootstrap:inputcheckbox path="active"  value="true" label="Yes" />
    </bootstrap:input>
    <bootstrap:input path="linkUrl" label="Link Url">
    <form:input path="linkUrl" cssClass="input-xlarge"/>
    </bootstrap:input>
    <bootstrap:input path="linkTarget" label="Link Target">
    <form:select path="linkTarget" >
    <form:option value="_blank" label="_blank"/>
    <form:option value="_self" label="_self"/>
    </form:select>
    </bootstrap:input>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-actions">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/content/carousel/list" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    </form:form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </c:set>
    <jsp:include page="../templates/baserender.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="_wPageTitle" value="Add Carousel"/>
        <jsp:param name="mainBody" value="${mainBody}"/>
    </jsp:include>
```

Comment: Are you accessing image from another class, from a view,... ? Can you also show us that code pls.

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace of the exception in your question, including any 'Caused by' parts.

Comment: The image doesn't exist yet. The error shows up on a view, which simply displays a form. Following is the full stack trace:

Comment: Edit your answer and add the stacktrace, don't share it in a link. If the link goes down, your question isn't complete anymore.

Comment: Also add your JSP view, I think the error will be in there...

Comment: Yeah my spidey senses are just starting to tell me that. Still a bit clueless though. I haven't dealt with java in over 5 years.

Comment: I doubt this will be too helpful, but it doesn't appear to change the behavior at all if I remove the file input for the 'image' property. Also the edit and list views work just fine.

Comment: This issue can be closed. There doesn't appear to be a problem with this code. I just couldn't get it to deploy it seems.